# Ubuntu 18.04 проблемы с NTFS дисками

Tags: ubuntu, ntfs

дорогие программисты!

У меня установлен Ubuntu 18.04, И иногда происходить такое что на NTFS дисков не  могу создать файлы, папки и прочие. Выводит что *файловая система доступна только для чтение.*

И после выполнение следующих команд и перезагрузив лептоп могу уже создавать папки, файлы и все такое.

1. sudo ntfsfix /dev/sda1 && sudo chown -R root:root /media/erobererit
2. sudo ntfsfix /dev/sda2 && sudo chown -R root:root /media/erobererit

Но при таком, данные находившимся на файлах, меняется кодировка или совсем удаляется.

Такое часто бывает.. Если кто-то, когда-то сталкивался с такой проблемой и исправил все на ура.. Поделитесь, пожалуйста. Буду очень благодарен.

Comment: А другая ось на компе есть?

Comment: Да. Windows 10 установлен.

Comment: Ты не так завершаешь работу в винде. Она кладёт себя в сон или гибернацию. А надо - классическое завершение работы.

Comment: Иногда, после работы просто закрываю не выключив, чтобы потом дома еще поработать.. Из-за этого может возникать ошибки??

Comment: Скорее всего - как раз из-за этого.

Comment: Спасибо, don Rumata. :)

Answer (score -1):

Выключение  винды  не помогало решить проблему. Помогло  отключение и последующее удаление всех дисков из диспетчера задач. Возможно еще помогло действие в кмд SHUTDOWN с параметром /s PS windows 10. После этих действий диски  стали соответствовать заданным правам пользователя  linux